# Avi to Mpeg conversion with using C#

Tags: c#, video, mpeg

Yes i want to convert avi file to mpeg file..This will be first experience for me..I am so newbie at this..Is converting avi to mpeg possible with using C#.
If yes,what i have to  do? Which article i have to read?

Comment: best to start looking at this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/avifilewrapper.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

This is a quite complicated topic that you'll want to relegate to a 3rd party component.  The most widely used tool is ffmpeg which you can call from c# by launching it as a child process.

http://www.ffmpeg.org/

> FFmpeg is a complete, cross-platform solution to record, convert and stream audio and video.

Due to licensing restrictions it's generally not available as a binary download--you'll need to download source and compile it yourself.